# How to create mock object of a class which is package private

Tags: scala, companion-object, scalamock, package-private

I have a class. It has a companion object `A` with a factory method.

class A private[somepackage](x: Int) {

}

object A {
 def createA(y: Int): A = {
  new A(y)
}
}

Now I need to create the mock object of `A` in a scalatest file which is in a different package.

When I give

private val a = mock[A] --> I get compilation error.

constructor `A` in class `A` cannot be accessed in <<`somewhere`>>.
Is there a better way to mock the object ??

Comment: well I hate to be that guy, but if this is code in your own base then it needs some tweaking - not really a workaround I'd recommend exploring. This is a code smell. That being said, you can use reflections to change accessibility of objects

Answer (score 1):

In your test sources, create a test double in the same package:

```
package somepackage

class MockableA extends A(0)
```

then just create a `mock[MockableA]` in your tests and continue as usual.

But the answer with a proxy/facade should work too if you are willing to change production sources to facilitate tests.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a proxy to access class A, and stub/mock that proxy class instead.
E.g., if `A.doStuff` is what you want to mock/stub, and `A.accessStuff` is what you need in your code, create a class

```
class ADecorated(underlying: A) {
  def doStuff() {
    underlying.doStuff()
    // whatever I want to do
  }

  def accessStuff() {
    x = underlying.accessStuff()
    // do something else and return
  }
 // Any other method you want to use
}
```

Replace usage of `A.createA` with new `ADecorated(A.createA())`. `ADecorated` is what you work with now